# Impossible to use chown even if I am logged as a root

Tags: debian, operation, chown

I am currently using debian 6 squeeze. I would like to change the owner of a floder in my usb key.
So I did :
`chown -R www-data /media/USB/myfolder/myfile`

I got this message :

> chown: changing ownership of `/media/USB/myfolder/myfile': Operation not permitted

I googled it, indeed my partition is a vfat and then I did :
`vim /etc/fstab`

Then I add at the end of the file (44 is the uid of www-data):
`default,utf8,umask=077,uid=44,gid=44`

I rebooted and I got the same error as in the beggining

`chown: changing ownership of /media/USB/myfolder/myfile': Operation not permitted`

Then I replaced the line in /etc/fstab by
`default,utf8,umask=077,uid=0,gid=0`

I got the same problem after rebooting

Can anyone help me,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `default,utf8,umask=077,uid=44,gid=44` this in your FSTAB, the files should be owned by www-data.  The ownership of files on mounted FAT partition is set by the mount command, and can't be changed after that; the partition itself can't record any changes to ownership.

Comment: It is not the case. when I do a umount then mount, it is owned by root as I am root on my machine

Comment: @Mr_Kaz Try putting the uid parameters directly on the mount command you use rather than in fstab: mount -o utf8,umask=077,uid=44,gid=44 <usb key path> <mount path>

Comment: It doesn't work. 
But I ound out how to deal with that : the fat partition don't support the system of file owning. I should mount the usb key as the user I want he has the rights.
thank you antlersoft